# GekkoMiner USB Help

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-hardware

I just received my first Gekkoscience USB Miner but I am having trouble setting it up. Could someone explain it too me how in baby words with download links and stuff?

I got it to some what work but not mine:

```
cgminer.exe -o stratum+tcp://sha.eobot.com:3333 -u eobot.396718 --compac-freq 150
```

When I run it this is what I get. Any clue?

```
 [2016-05-20 20:38:18.637] No devices detected!
 [2016-05-20 20:38:18.637] Waiting for USB hotplug devices or press q to quit
 [2016-05-20 20:38:18.637] Probing for an alive pool
 [2016-05-20 20:38:18.819] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 1024
 [2016-05-20 20:38:19.638] Network diff set to 194G
 [2016-05-20 20:38:24.990] USB init, open device failed, err -12,
 [2016-05-20 20:38:24.991] You need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 1:21
 [2016-05-20 20:38:24.993] And associate - AMU device 1:21 with WinUSB using zadig
 [2016-05-20 20:38:24.994] See README.txt file included for help
 [2016-05-20 20:38:24.996] Icarus detect (1:21) failed to initialise (incorrect device?)
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.357] USB init, open device failed, err -12,
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.358] You need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 1:21
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.360] And associate - AMU device 1:21 with WinUSB using zadig
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.362] See README.txt file included for help
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.363] Icarus detect (1:21) failed to initialise (incorrect device?)
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.715] USB init, open device failed, err -12,
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.717] You need to install a WinUSB driver for - GEK device 1:21
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.719] And associate - GEK device 1:21 with WinUSB using zadig
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.721] See README.txt file included for help
 [2016-05-20 20:38:25.723] Gekko detect (1:21) failed to initialise (incorrect device?)
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Windows you need "zadig" to install the proper driver for your hardware. If using Linux simply update the system via `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Then try again. Unplug mining device(s) and plug back in.
I don't recognize the pool you've chosen but I think, you should have a `-p` followed by your password. The password can be literally "anything". Also, when you run `cgminer` you can type "u" for usb manangment then "e" for enable and enter the values it asks for.